# Unable to click on particular element. I have tried locating object using xpath, css, creating your own xpath and css but none of the is working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class XpathDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("http://www.amazon.in/");
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("b[style='padding-right:3px; font-weight:normal;font-size: 18px;text-transform: uppercase;']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Sign in")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class = '.nav-action-inner']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ap_email")).sendKeys("vit.yoamitsharma@gmail.com");
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[7]/div[2]/a/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Whats the error here?
2. I see 2 un-commented lines trying to click sign in button.
3. Have you tried with xpath checker? following should work and it worked for me

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[7]/div[2]/a/span")).click();